# how to select only one value sql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a table like this

```
_______________
|id   |  Name | 
|1    | Joe   |
|2    | Mike  |



__________________________
|id   | Phone | contactID|
|1    | 1234  | 1        |
|2    | 5678  | 1        |
|3    | 9999  | 2        |
|4    | 8888  | 2        |
|5    | 7777  | 2        |
```

I need to show the name and phone numbers of each user. But now only one number is displayed. How can I get all phone numbers to be shown with name showing only once?

Comment: Which one? A random one? The first/last by any specific order? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: A lot of systems may have multiple phone numbers of 1 person, but usually they are identified by a type - home/mobile/primary/emergency etc.  This means you can pick a meaningful number to print when you need to.

Answer (score 1):

```
Table - User
_______________
|id   |  Name | 
|1    | Joe   |
|2    | Mike  |


Table - Contact
__________________________
|id   | Phone | contactID|
|1    | 1234  | 1        |
|2    | 5678  | 1        |
|3    | 9999  | 2        |
|4    | 8888  | 2        |
|5    | 7777  | 2        |
```

First you have to run mysql query

```
SELECT u.Name, c.Phone 
FROM User u 
INNER JOIN Contact c ON c.contactID = u.id 
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Now you store your mysql query result and run a loop to print every name only one phone number